# Not getting the right output on running the PowerShell script given below

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I have written the below code but, the output is repeated for arount 37 times. Can anyone please help me to find where I am wrong.

---

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity $Url
        $root = $site.RootWeb
        $bu1web = $site.OpenWeb("Bu1")
        $listRequest=$bu1web.Lists["Requests"]
        $requestitems = $listRequest.items

        if($listRequest -ne $null ) 
        {
            foreach($requestitem in $requestitems)
            { 
                foreach($workflow in $requestitem.workflows)
                    {

                    $historys=$workflow.HistoryList.Items
                    #$tasks=$workflow.Tasks
                    foreach($history in $historys)
                    {
                        if(($history["Description"] -eq "No User/Group assigned to the task.") -And (($workflow.InternalState -eq "Running, Faulting") -Or ($workflow.InternalState -eq "Cancelled, Faulting")))
                        {
                                #Write-Log $("Request ID:"+$requestitem["ID"] + "--WorkFlowName:" +$workflow.ParentAssociation.Name) $logFile "info"    
                                Write-Log $("Request ID:"+$requestitem["ID"]+"--Status:"+$workflow.InternalState+"--Event Type:"+$history["EventType"] + "--Description:" +$history["Description"]) $logFile "info"           
                        }
                    }
                    }#end of foreach workflow loop
            }# end of checking if workflow associations count is greater than one
        }#end ofRequest list null check
```

---

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

`$workflow.HistoryList.Items` get all the history of the workflow history list in the site, not only for an item.

You need to filter with workflow instance ID.